# gridview with radiobuttonlist template field

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding, gridview

I have created a `gridview` with radio button list. It throws error like

```
RadioButtonList2' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

And this is my coding to bind in a `gridview`

```
q = "SELECT 
        s.rollno,
        s.studname,
        d.deptname,
        ct.ctype,
        c.course,
        s.status 
    FROM
        dbmasdeptcreat d,
        dbmascoursetypecreat ct,
        dbmascoursecreat c,
        dbmasstuddet s 
    WHERE 
        s.deptid=d.deptid AND 
        s.ctypeid=ct.ctypeid AND 
        s.cid=c.cid AND 
        s.status <> 'ACTIVE' AND 
        s.collname='" & lablcollname.Text & "'"

        ds = c1.getDataset(q)
        GridView2.DataSource = ds
        GridView2.DataBind()
        GridView2.Visible = True
```

And this is my gridview source coding

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rollno" HeaderText="Rollno" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="studname" HeaderText="Student Name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="deptname" HeaderText="Department " ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course" HeaderText="Course Type" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course" HeaderText="Course" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' >
                    <asp:ListItem>GUEST</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>REGULAR</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You might want to add a few more tags so we know what language or system you're working with.

Comment: You know your query is vulnerable to sql injection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't attached your code properly, please attach it again and are you populating that radio button list with some kind of data source like SQL Data Source ? because this kind of error usually occurs when the value from data source does not match any value in the collection of values that you defined for radio button list for example if you defined values like

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

for radio button list and data source is returning Mango then the radio button list will throw this kind of error because it cannot select Mango as its not available in its defined collection.

If you provide code I can help you better.